# Grails consume SOAP with WSDL + pojo/pogo?

Tags: grails, soap, groovy, wsdl, cxf

I have to **call some SOAP webservices in my grails app** (grails 2.4.5 + groovy 2.3) and ideally, I'd like to do so **using the WSDL description** of the services, since everything seems to be set up in it (actions, parameters, returns, ...). 1 month with hands on grail, 3 years on JAVA, none on webservices.

---

**First,** It seems that I must forget the "so easy and already packaged" way consisting in using **GroovyWS** since the project seems to be abandonned and the links brokens. Too bad.

---

**Then** I went to look at the **grails CXF plugin** ([Grails CXF Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/cxf-client)). After hours of digging in the CXF Plugin project and Plugin demo project I succeeded in generating about 30 java class from my WSDL, but couldn't inject anything in my controller using this kind of syntax :

```
class DemoController {
SimpleServicePortType simpleServiceClient
ComplexServicePortType complexServiceClient

def simpleServiceDemo = {
    SimpleRequest request = new SimpleRequest(age: 100, name: "Bob")
    SimpleResponse response = simpleServiceClient.simpleMethod(request)

    render(view: '/index', model: [simpleRequest: request, simpleResponse: response])
}
```

I generated a WSSessionSOAP class which seems perfect (every operation, parameters, ...) but that's an interface ... In the project example, I saw that the developer define the behaviour of the services, so I guess he is more "exposing" a WS than consuming it.
Is it really possible to generate classes from a WSDL and use them to call the SOAP services ? Would seem so natural !

---

**Finally**, I gave a look to the [Grails WSlite Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/wslite) and succeeded to call a WS (yay !) this way :

```
withSoap(serviceURL: 'https://XXX/webservices/session.asmx') {
  def response = send(SOAPAction: 'http://XXX/Session/CheckSession') {
    body {
      CheckSession(xmlns : 'http://XXX/Session') { guid(chaine) }
    }
  }
  render response.CheckSessionResponse.CheckSessionResult.text()
}
```

That's a first step, OK for simple services (for the moment) but I feel like reinventing the wheel and not capitalizing on the OO aspect of the WSDL.

Is it the good/best/only way to consume SOAP services (with clean grails services, of course) ? Do the CXF plugin has a chance to anwser to my needs ? What Have I missed ? I read so many pages, but most of the time the examples are too generics or outdated.

---

I know there is some other solutions:

- Using a full Java API to generate a "WebServices" part and use it in my grails services/controllers, but again, is it the best way to do it ?
- Call my WS with good old HTTP GET requests. Wouldn't it be an affront ?

Sorry if I may consider absurd options but this is driving me crazy, I feel like I'm spending way too much time on this, with for only result a "0" response to a little WS.

Feel free to ask me anything I would have forgot.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have the same issue, and the worst part is soapAction is actually empty in the wsdl so no ideal what to put in `send`. keep getting `Root element is definitions, expected Envelope`